# Django 2.0 static no autocomplete in PyCharm 2017.2.4

Tags: django, pycharm

Autocomplete is not working for static files for me with Django 2.0.

I'm using static files in my project with the current structure

```
project
-app_1
-templates
--base.html
-static
--bootstrap
---bootstrap.min.cs
---bootstrap.min.js
```

Here's the HTML code where autocomplete doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

The files are linked properly and I'm getting the bootstrap design, the problem is that the autocomplete isn't working.

Here's my static settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this on two different computers and projects in two different ways.

The first project uses settings module instead of a single file like this
settings
- **init**.py
- shared.py
- prod.py
- dev.py
Autocomplete for static started working after I set the proper path to settings like this:
[image]

In the second instance I had a settings.py file and autocomplete started working when I replaced my AppConfig with app name in settings INSTALLED_APPS like this, though I'm inclined to think this is just some kind of bug:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'depapp', # Used to be depapp.apps.DepappConfig
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mark the directory as "Resource"?

[image]

Comment: Yeah just did, nothing changed